# Reading XLS file using Perl

Tags: perl, xls

This is my Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

    use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
    use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
    my $workbook   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new("/home/Admin/Desktop/RP_processed_Address_withsubscriptionID (1).xls");
    my $workbook1 = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("/home/Admin/Desktop/new.xls");
    open(my$old, '<', "$workbook") or die "oops!";
    open(my$new, '>', "$workbook1") or die "ooops!";
    while (my$line = <$workbook>) {
        print $workbook1 $line

    }
```

When I run this Script I'm getting following error

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/local/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 167.
oops! at sample.pl line 9.
```

I'm not getting any idea where is script is going wrong . Please help me how to resolve this error 
your suggestions will be appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

You are not reading any docs again. You copy and paste code and don't understand the basics of what you do. Why are you opening files using `open` when you already open them using the two modules? Why do you write a line manually? This is not how excel data works, this is not how the modules work. Stop guessing. Learn what you're doing. This will never work.

Comment: before i never work on xls files . I did as like .csv file that's why i posted sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CPAN for [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm)

You need to access the worksheets within the workbook object you've created and determine which you would like to parse data from.  From here you can access cells using the column/width coordinate system.  You don't need to use 'open' as the ParseExcel and WriteExcel already do this.

```
my $sheet = $workbook1->worksheet('Sheet1');
my $cell = $sheet->get_cell( 0, 0 );
my $cell_value = $cell->value();
```

Is it a bit more clear on what you need to do?